# How to generate SHA1 check-sum of an SSL Certificate which uses sha1WithRSAEncryption?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

SSL certificate of any server can be verified by checking if the Signature decrypted with the public key from it's issuer's certificate and the Check sum of server certificate are equal.

How can I find the check sum of a certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the contents of the certificate, it will generally tell you which algorithm it uses for hashing. For instance, `RSAwithSHA1` tells you that the contents of the certificate will be hashed using the [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) algorithm and then digitally signed using the RSA private key of the certificate issuer. To verify the certificate, you need to fetch the RSA public key of the issuer and obtain the original hash from the signature. Then calculate the SHA1 hash of the certificate contents (excluding the signature) and match it with the obtained hash. Both values should be the same. You can calculate SHA1 hash using tools like `sha1sum` on Linux or `shasum` on Mac.

Comment: Yes, and the question is exactly how can I calculate the SHA1 hash of the certificate contents (excluding the signature). I have a script written to do all the operations but need the algorithm to make the check-sum excluding the signature